# Can a custom knit_hooks set options before and after R chunk?

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to specify text (specifically a div tag) before and after some R code in a Rmd file using github_document. I can't seem to get both the before and after to work.

For example knitting the following:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: github_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)        
knit_hooks$set(toggle = function(before, options, envir) {
      if(options$toggle){
        if(before) {
          print('<div id="hideMe">')
        } else {
          print("</div>")
        }
      }
    })

```

## GitHub Documents


```{r pressure, echo=TRUE, toggle=TRUE}
# Here's some
```
````

Produces:

````
Untitled
================

GitHub Documents
----------------

``` r
# Here's some
```
````

If I delete the `else` part:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: github_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)        
knit_hooks$set(toggle = function(before, options, envir) {
      if(options$toggle){
        if(before) {
          print('<div id="hideMe">')
        } 
      }
    })

```

## GitHub Documents


```{r pressure, echo=TRUE, toggle=TRUE}
# Here's some
```
````

It works as expected, and I get the `before` section:

````
Untitled
================

GitHub Documents
----------------

<div id="hideMe">

``` r
# Here's some
```
````

If I use `!before` in the if statement, the trailing `</div>` shows up. But I have been unable to get both the leading and trailing sections to show up. Any suggestions to get *both* before and after text to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Don't print in chunk hooks, return the text that is to be added to the document:

> In knitr, hooks can also be used to insert texts into the output. To do this, the hook function must return a character result. [[Source]](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#chunk_hooks)

The most likely explanation for the behavior you observed is that in R, "`if` returns the value of the expression evaluated" (see `?Control` section "Value").